# iphone localization

Tags: iphone

hello all when i run the command to generate Localizable.string file from my terminal it says me bad entry in to the classes file the file gets generated but it has no entry in it infact it should have entry in it. Here is what i am running in my terminal but somehow it is not happening please guide me need to solve this

```
Last login: Mon Jun  7 18:02:09 on ttys000
comp10:~ admin$ cd ..
comp10:Users admin$ cd ..
comp10:/ admin$ cd /Users/admin/Desktop/localisationwithcode 
comp10:localisationwithcode admin$ sudo
usage: sudo -K | -L | -V | -h | -k | -l | -v
usage: sudo [-HPSb] [-p prompt] [-u username|#uid]
            { -e file [...] | -i | -s | <command> }
comp10:localisationwithcode admin$ genstrings Classes/*.m
Bad entry in file Classes/localisationwithcodeViewController.m (line = 35): Argument is not a literal string.
Bad entry in file Classes/localisationwithcodeViewController.m (line = 36): Argument is not a literal string.
Bad entry in file Classes/localisationwithcodeViewController.m (line = 37): Argument is not a literal string.
Bad entry in file Classes/localisationwithcodeViewController.m (line = 38): Argument is not a literal string.
2010-06-07 18:04:45.047 genstrings[3851:10b] _CFGetHostUUIDString: unable to determine UUID for host. Error: 35
comp10:localisationwithcode admin$
```

Comment: Have u take any reference from blog...

Answer (score 0):

You have an alternative way to solve Issue:
1.Right click on your Project Name From Groups and Files
2.From there Click on **Resources** Tag(Mac OS)
3.On That you will get tag like **String File** Clink on that File and Name as per your Requirement...